# Is it possible to use thrust::device_ptr on a mapped array?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to use the thrust::copy_if function on mapped memory. However, as I get a runtime error and I am not being able to find it, before spending a lot of time in debugging, I would like to have a confirmation of the fact that it is effectively allowed to pass a pointer to a mapped memory location to the thrust::device_ptr wrapper.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
int size=1024;

int* v_locked;
int* v_device;
int* stencil_device;

device_ptr<int> v_wrapper;
device_ptr<int> v_wrapper_end;
device_ptr<int> stencil_wrapper;

cudaHostAlloc((void**)&v_locked, size*sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocMapped));
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&v_device, &v_locked, 0);

cudaMalloc((void**)&stencil_device, size*sizeof(int));
/* 
kernel assigning stencil_device elements ...
*/

v_wrapper = device_pointer_cast(v_device);
stencil_wrapper = device_pointer_cast(stencil_device);

v_wrapper_end = copy_if(make_counting_iterator<int>(0), make_counting_iterator<int>(size), stencil_wrapper, v_wrapper, _1 == 1);
```

Is this a correct usage of mapped memory with thrust library?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I believe there were several problems with your code.

1. You don't appear to be doing any [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)  If you were, you would have detected that although your calls to `cudaHostGetDevicePointer` seem to compile correctly, they were not set up correctly.
2. As mentioned above, your calls to `cudaHostGetDevicePointer()` were not set up correctly.  The second pointer argument is passed as a single pointer (`*`), not double pointer (`**`).  Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ga475419a9b21a66036029d5001ea908c)  This call as written would throw a cuda runtime error which you can trap.
3. Prior to your `cudaHostAlloc` calls, you should use the `cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);` call to [enable this feature](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g18074e885b4d89f5a0fe1beab589e0c8).

Here is a sample code which seems to work correctly for me, and has the above problems fixed:

```
$ cat t281.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>   

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

template<typename T>
struct is_one : thrust::unary_function<T, bool>
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const T &x)
    {
        return (x==1);
    }
};

int main(){

  int size=1024;

  int* v_locked;
  int* v_device;
  int* stencil_locked;
  int* stencil_device;

  cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaSetDeviceFlags");
  cudaHostAlloc((void**)&v_locked, size*sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocMapped);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaHostAlloc 1");
  cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&v_device, v_locked, 0);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaHostGetDevicePointer 1");
  cudaHostAlloc((void**)&stencil_locked, size*sizeof(int), cudaHostAllocMapped);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaHostAlloc 2");
  cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&stencil_device, stencil_locked, 0);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaHostGetDevicePointer 2");

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    v_locked[i] = i;
    stencil_locked[i] = i%2;}

  thrust::device_ptr<int> v_wrapper = thrust::device_pointer_cast(v_device);
  thrust::device_ptr<int> stencil_wrapper = thrust::device_pointer_cast(stencil_device);
  thrust::device_ptr<int> v_wrapper_end = v_wrapper + size;
  thrust::device_vector<int> result(size);
  thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator result_end = copy_if(v_wrapper, v_wrapper_end, stencil_wrapper, result.begin(), is_one<int>());
  int result_size = result_end - result.begin();
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_result(result_size);
  thrust::copy_n(result.begin(), result_size, h_result.begin());
  thrust::copy_n(h_result.begin(), 10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t281 t281.cu
$ ./t281
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
$
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Indeed, I do error checking in my code, but I did not report it into the piece of code posted because I thought this one should be _minimal_. The same, I did not report the call to `cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost)`, but I do it in the code. The error I was doing in the call to `cudaHostGetDevicePointer()` was not signaled to me at runtime by the error check function I was using in the call itself, but subsequently, when I accessed the array, for which reason I did not notice it. Now I've replaced the error check function with the one suggested, thanks.